# Android - Performance issue on RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, linearlayoutmanager

I have a `NestedScrollView` in which `RecyclerView` and a `RelativeLayout` lies inside..

It's basically this way

```
<NestedScrollView>

<RelativeLayout> //To contain the stuffs inside

    <RelativeLayout /> // Contains a `TextView` and a `ProgressBar`

    <RecyclerView /> // The most important thing.. Maybe

</RelativeLayout>

</NestedScrollView>
```

I am using a `CustomLinearLayoutManager` and `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` in order to scroll both `RelativeLayout` and `RecyclerView` together, else, only the `RecyclerView` will scroll, the `RelativeLayout` will just stay on top of it.

Whenever the `RecyclerView` loads new data, it freezes for 3-5 seconds which is very bad for user experience.. This is the `CustomLayoutManager` which I am using..

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public CustomLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    /**
     * Disable predictive animations. There is a bug in RecyclerView which causes views that
     * are being reloaded to pull invalid ViewHolders from the internal recycler stack if the
     * adapter size has decreased since the ViewHolder was recycled.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supportsPredictiveItemAnimations() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        heightSpec,
                        mMeasuredDimension);

                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                        widthSpec,
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        mMeasuredDimension);
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }
        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        recycler.bindViewToPosition(view, position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

I actually only copied the `CustomLayoutManager` from another SO answer, it might be or might not be the problem..

Comment: I think it is not because of CustomLayoutManager. I have the same problem with LinearLayoutManager. RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView works slow for me too. Here is a sample project which demonstrates differences in performance https://github.com/sirekanyan/android-recyclerview-inside-a-nestedscrollview (loading 1000 TextView items inside RecyclerView take several seconds on my device)

Comment: In the end, I put everything inside RecyclerView by overriding `getItemViewType()`, I can set which item is placed in the position. This question was when I was a super newb at Android lol